# Android App UI too small on some devices

Tags: android, user-interface, resolution

I changed API level of SDK for my application **from 13 to 24**. After that some users tell me: **Application UI is ~10x smaller than should be**. Very-very small icons and microscopic text. Devices:

- Samsung A5 (Android 6.0)
- Samsung A7 (Android 6.0)
- Lenovo P1ma40 (Android 5.1)
- I suspect Samsung A6 and some others.

On the most of devices app works well. Only several models has this issue.

Please, help..

**Edit.** Here are two UI-screenshots:

1. From a user
2. As it should be

[image: From a user] [image: As it should be]

From AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<supports-screens> 
    <android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="false" 
    android:smallScreens="false" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="false">
</supports-screens>
```

**Edit 2.** Removing `anyDensity` tag fixed issue.

Comment: Which image/icon density qualifiers are you using in your APK? Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include screenshots of the correct and incorrect behavior for your UI, along with the code and resources that implement that UI.

Comment: I use ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi

Comment: attached two screenshots...

Answer (score 1):

you should use constraint layout . and add vertical or horizontal guideline with percentage.